# Insert all data from an already sorted table into another

Tags: sql, insert, amazon-redshift

I have two tables in an Amazon Redshift cluster that both use a timestamp as sort key. The first table  is sorted and contains only data from timepoint 1 to timepoint 2. The second table is only temporary but also sorted and contains data from timepoint 3 to timepoint 4. Is there any to insert all the data from the first table into the second without having to run VACUUM on the table as. A normal INSERT from one table to another always needs a VACUUM afterwards as far as I know.

I know it would be possible if I used COPY on a pre-sorted flat file. But is there also a solution for two pre-sorted tables that does not need a VACUUM?

Comment: Hi, I have the same question, I will be happy for an answer. BTW do you think that "insert into select order" by will insert the rows in a sorted order? Is the an official recommendation of amazon to use order by by sortkey in "insert into select"?

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

create new table say final table same schema as table two as you wish to copy content of table 1 to table 2.

Please check

```
select "column", type, encoding 
from pg_table_def where tablename='table2'
```

this will give encoding used for each column for table 2. Create new final table with same encoding for each column.

Use query to load data in final table in sorted order

```
insert into final table ( select * from table1 order by timepoint asc)
```

then fire

```
insert into final table ( select * from table2 order by timepoint asc )
```

Option 2:

create final table and load data for timpoint1 , then load for timepoint2.. Continue till time points loaded in sorted manner.

Option 3:

You can check for Deep **Copy Redshift** option as well
here is the link http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/performing-a-deep-copy.html

While doing deep copy, copy data for table 1 first then load table 2

Comment: Thank you for answering my question! Does Reshift mark the blocks as sorted when I use option 1 or 2? I understand that the blocks are inserted pre-sorted but right now we have the problem that data-blocks that are inserted pre-sorted are not marked as sorted and therefore the next VACUUM command tries to sort them again.

Comment: Option 1 only works with the COPY command and even then, only if all of the following conditions apply: 1. The table uses a compound sort key with only one sort column.
2. The sort column is NOT NULL.
3. The table is 100 percent sorted or empty.
4. All the new rows are higher in sort order than the existing rows.
see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/vacuum-load-in-sort-key-order.html

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this query in SQL Server :

> SELECT * INTO table_name FROM old_table_name